# How to represent a Pascal-esque (equilateral) triangle in memory

Tags: data-structures, tree

I was working on [Project Euler Problem 18](https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) (I **did** solve the problem; I'm not cheating. "[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MDTC.png)" here) and found myself in need of a way to represent a data structure that looks like a Pascal triangle, but with different values. It looks very similar to a binary tree, but there's a very important distinction: a node's children are not exclusively its children. So the first three rows look like this:

```
    75
   /  \
  95  64
 /  \ / \
17  47  82
```

Note that 47 has two parents.

It's pretty easy to represent this as a linked structure, or even a two-dimensional array, but I'm hoping that there's a more elegant way. I love binary trees, mainly for how you can allocate a single chunk of memory, treat it as an array, and **navigate between children and parent with a couple of arithmetic operations** or integer division. **Is there a way to do the same for this data structure?**

My best solution involved using a two-dimensional array (where it's very easy to find children and parents). I dislike this implementation because (at least the way I did it) I called `malloc` for every row, even though I knew how big the structure would be ahead of time.

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341487/how-to-represent-a-binomial-tree-in-memory), but I wasn't happy with the accepted answer. A comment alludes to the solution I seek, but no explanation is given.

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm looking for a way to **index into a one-dimensional array** in the same way that an binary tree stuffed sequentially into an array (starting at 1) gives the property that the children of a node at index *i* are at indexes 2 * *i* and 2 * *i* + 1. I'm also not very concerned about being able to find parents, so don't worry too much about the weird two parent.

Comment: That's not a "tree" as far as I know, that's a *cyclic graph*. [This question looks like what you want, or at least a good starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615202/c-sharp-graph-traversal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to store a triangular data structure in a one-dimensional array (example in Java):

```
class Triangle<T> {
  private T[] triangle;

  public Triangle(T[] array, int rows) {
    if (array.length != triangleNumber(rows)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array wrong size");
    }
    triangle = array;
  }

  public T get(int row, int col) {
    return triangle[index(row, col)];
  }

  public void set(int row, int col, T val) {
    triangle[index(row, col)] = val; 
  }

  private int triangleNumber(int rows) {
    return rows * (rows + 1) / 2;
  }

  private int index(int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || col > row) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Trying to access outside of triangle");
    }
    return triangleNumber(row) + col;
  }
}
```

The array passed to the constructor is formed by concatenating the rows of the triangle one-by-one into the array: [t(0,0), t(1,0), t(1,1), t(2,0), t(2,1), t(2,2), ... , t(rows-1, rows-1)], where t(R, C) is the triangle cell at triangle row R and triangle column C.

For any cell (row, col):

- left child would be at row+1, col
- right child would be at row+1, col+1
- left parent would be at row-1, col-1
- right parent would be at row-1, col

Two parents and two children do not exist for all cells because they would lie outside the triangle. See the exception check in the index method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is :
We start with your idea of a two-dimentional array , but with irregular row length.So each element is indexed by a two dimentional index (r,c);
        (1,1)
     (2,1)(2,2)
   (3,1)(3,2)(3,3)
(4,1)(4,2)(4,3)(4,4)

Because the relationship are regular, you can express the positions we have :
for a node (r,c) is childrens are (r+1,min(1,c)),(r+1,max(c+1,r)) and his parent are : (r-1,min(1,c-1)),(r-1,max(c,r))

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to get rid of the two-dimensional array. Please see my edit.

Comment: @Jay you mean a way to index with only one index?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm sure it's a silly distinction, but I'm curious whether it's possible or not.

Comment: @jay, it is , but it wont be at linear function as in the case of the binary tree